# Is it possible to make query with join and union?

Tags: mysql

I want to make query something like this...

```
select table1.col1, table1.col2, table1.col3 from table1 union
select table2col1, table1col2, table2col3 from table2
left join table2 on table1.col1 = table2.col1
```

I want my some columns from table1 in table2 because I know in table2 there are missing some columns which I need from table1 to complete standard of union by which I am using joining, but I also want union of two tables

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(select table1.col1, table1.col2, table1.col3 from table1 )
union
(select table2col1, table1col2, table2col3 from table2
left join table1 on table1.col1 = table2.col1)
```